# Close app requiring location-services if user selects "Don't Allow"?

Tags: iphone, xcode, cllocationmanager, userlocation

I have an app whose core functionality revolves around the use of the user's current location. It shows objects near the user on the map. I don't create a location manager, I just use the mapview's. This works well, but now I'm trying to make sure my app alerts the user correctly of it's need for location-services. What I'm doing now is creating a new location manager in the applicationDidBecomeActive method, and attempting to start updating in order to trigger a request for permission from the user whenever the app opens or comes back from the background with location-services off like this:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    CLLocationManager *manager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
    {
        NSLog(@"yes");
    }
    [manager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

**Question 1:** Is this a good way of doing it?

**Question 2:** Since every aspect of my app uses location-services would it be appropriate to close the app if the user selects "Don't Allow" when they are prompted that my app would like to use location-services?

Any other advise from experience with dealing with location-services and the notifications and requests to the user would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "close" an app--Apple doesn't allow it, and there's actually no public API to "quit".

What you can do instead is throw up a view that takes over the whole screen explaining the failure to operate properly without CoreLocation permission. Maybe even with a button making CLLocationManager prompt them for permission again.

Comment: ok that makes sense, so when they dismiss that view I would try to "startUpdatingLocation" on a location manager again to trigger the system prompt again, right? Sorry, one more question, can you access the mapview's own locationmanager to tell it to start updating?

Comment: @Ryan - You know, I'm not certain about that. You might have to give them directions to go into their system prefs and unblock you. That's a better answer anyway--they may have location services turned off before you even get there, so it makes sense to be able to instruct them out of that. And if location services are blocked (either globally or for your app), they're blocked in MapKit too.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Actually, if it's turned off when they open the app and a location manager tries to update for the first time, it automatically shows them an alert with a link to settings. if not for Apple being so picky, I wouldn't even deal with someone using the app, exiting it to turn of location services, then reopening it since that's a very unlikely scenario, but who knows if apple will check for that:) Multitasking makes things complicated:(

Answer (score 0):

It is against apple's guidelines to close an app programatically and doing so will likely get it rejected.